# Pros and Cons of opening wall between kitchen and dining room

Tags: kitchens

we have a wall between kitchen and dining room. We plan on making an opening about 5' x 3' in the wall.

Below the wall will be kitchen sink.

What are the pros and cons of making such opening ?

Comment: This is really an opinion based question, not a "how to do it" question. The text of your question is also unclear:  How can a wall be below a kitchen sink?   Perhaps there is another area in SE that this question could be migrated to.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I think OP means below the opening that will be put in the wall, there will be a kitchen sink. Like a window frame but without any window in it.

Comment: There will be an opening and below the opening ( on kitchen side ) there will be a kitchen sink. In order words - somebody doing the dishes will be able to see the dining room. So my question is - what are pros of cons of such design ?

Comment: Again, this is an opinion based question and off topic here. But if you want my opinion....no way would I do that. The noise, odors and steam would interfere with the ambiance of the living room. Enjoy your meal, converse with family and friends and make your spouse help with the cleanup afterwards.   Again, totally my opinion. Structurally you might have an issue if it's a load bearing wall. You'll need to check that.

Comment: You could also add curtains or shutters to the opening to have a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Having an open layout will make the home feel larger and less constraining.
Before opening the wall:

1. make sure you dont have any plumbing, electrical, water in the area you want to open or else you'll have to move all of that to the side which involves lots of work.
2. check to make sure its not a weight bearing wall (you might have to install a header if it is).

The only con I could think of is that the 5' x 3' opening is pretty small and would make it look like a service window at the local DMV. Making the opening wider/taller would create the open space that pretty much all builders do now-a-days. If you post a picture of both side of the walls and possibly a layout, we could give our two cents.

Comment: If you decide to proceed, consider adding a shelf to the bottom of the opening, making it into a convenient pass-through for serving and collecting dishes.

Comment: I agree, +1. It is nice to have a view other than a blank wall when washing up. Plus you get to be part of any continuing conversations and/or shenanigans. We did this exact thing and never regretted it. We did make our opening larger, it did need a header, we did finish the bottom with a wide board with rounded ends and edges (stained and varnished), and we installed wood shutters.